# jQuery + Coldfusion: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I am using Coldfusion (8) and JS (not sure about the version).

I am getting problem with one drop-down. It should populate "book name" on the selection of "reading level". But I am getting mentioned error on browser console and drop-down doesn't populate anything (I checked the DB, books are present for the selected level).

The problem is intermittent. Sometimes book list loads and sometimes it doesn't.

[image: Console Error]

[image: Book Drop-Down]

Here are my two JS functions:

```
function select_level() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.assess_form.dralevel.length; i++) {
        if (document.assess_form.dralevel[i].selected) {
            dralevel = document.assess_form.dralevel[i].value;
        }
    }

    if (dralevel != document.assess_form.curr_dralevel.value) {
        document.assess_form.curr_dralevel.value = dralevel;

        if (is_dra) {
            if (dralevel < 14) {
                document.getElementById('time_off').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('time_on').style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('time_on').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('time_off').style.display = 'none';
            }

            reset_book();
        }
    }
}

function reset_book() {
    clear_sel(document.assess_form.book_id);

    if (document.assess_form.curr_dralevel.value == -1) {
        new_option = document.createElement('option');
        new_option.value = '0';
        new_option.text = 'First select a Reading Level';
        document.assess_form.book_id.options.add(new_option);
        document.assess_form.book_id.selectedIndex = 0;
    } else {
        book_ary = books[document.assess_form.curr_versionid.value][document.assess_form.curr_dralevel.value].split('^');

        new_option = document.createElement('option');
        new_option.value = '0';
        new_option.text = 'Select a book...';
        document.assess_form.book_id.options.add(new_option);
        document.assess_form.book_id.selectedIndex = 0;

        for (i = 0; i < book_ary.length; i++) {
            title_ary = book_ary[i].split('|');
            new_option = document.createElement('option');
            new_option.value = title_ary[1];
            new_option.text = title_ary[0];
            document.assess_form.book_id.options.add(new_option);
        }
    }

    document.assess_form.miscues.value = '';
    document.assess_form.minutes.selectedIndex = 0;
    document.assess_form.seconds.selectedIndex = 0;

    document.assess_form.curr_book_id.value = 0;
}
```

`Console.log(books)` - when it's working:

[image: console.log(error)]

`Console.log(books)` - when it's not working:

[image]

Comment: Which line are you getting this error at??

Comment: It should be `book_ary = books` here, right? Can you do a console.log(books) before this line and see what shows up in the console?

Comment: Also if you can show how the JS books variable is populated, that could help too.

Comment: @RRK: yes, i believe it's book_ary line which is causing the error. Weird part is - the error is intermittent, sometimes book loads and sometimes it doesnt. I have added console.log(books), please find results in the main question above.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty clear from your picture that the `books` object is empty when this error happens. **This is probably the real problem you need to solve.** You didn't provide any code that sets the value of `books` so we won't be able to tell why this is happening.

You're grabbing `books[document.assess_form.curr_versionid.value]` first, then trying to grab the `document.assess_form.curr_dralevel.value` property of whatever that's returning.

It's going to return `undefined` because `books` doesn't have any property, let alone the `document.assess_form.curr_versionid.value` one.

The offending line of code, as you pointed out:

```
book_ary = books[document.assess_form.curr_versionid.value][document.assess_form.curr_dralevel.value].split('^');
```

#### Reproducible

```
var books = { "Book1": "Book1Data", "Book2": "Book2Data"  };

// this line will generate an error because the output of books[1] is undefined
// thus, you can't call the [2] property on it
var book_ary = books[1][2]; // Cannot read property '2' of undefined
```

This is happening because you can't access a property of something that is `undefined` in this way, in `JavaScript`. The output of `books[1]` is `undefined`, therefore calling `books[1][2]` will produce the error.